# Why running executable in command line faster?

Tags: c++, command-line, compilation, g++

I coded a short program in C++ that is basically a method for filling an array of double with some math calculation through for loop, for the purpose of performance measurements and comparisons. I noticed that if I run the exe file through the command line (just type the file name and enter) I get significantly better results from `std::chrono` (wrapping the method within main method) than if I run it by double click the file. Does anyone have any idea why this performance difference might be due?

EDIT -- this is the function:

```
    double* MakeCalc()
    {
        double* retval = new double[5000 * 5000];
        int ind = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5000; j++)
            {
                retval[ind++] = i * j;
            }
        }
        delete[] retval;
        return retval;
    }

main function

    int main()
    {
        auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        MakeCalc();

        auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = chrono::duration<float>(end - start);

        std::cout << "execution time: " << duration.count() <<" sec" << '\n';

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It may depend on exactly how much work your program is doing.  Why don't you show your program?  It could be that the actual time taken is really small and so is more subject to other things like caching.  Or it could be that the two methods of creating the process you are testing result in a different priority in the OS -- for example in one case it might be executed by a different shell.  Or maybe you're printing out a lot of stuff and actually measuring the wrong thing.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Using the same executable or may one version be the debug build? Different loads on the CPU?

Comment: Thanks guys for your replies, much appreciated!. I added the code to my OP. I am on window10 x64. I activated O3 option when I compiled it.